# Android studio 1.0 Gradle error 1 - The specified path was not found

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I have just installed Android studio on a win 7 and wanted to compile the first sample code but the compiling fails

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

:app:preBuil
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72102Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42102Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug

Den angivne sti blev ikke fundet. (The specified path was not found.)

 FAILED

Den angivne sti blev ikke fundet. (The specified path was not found.)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
C:\Users\Sigmac\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat --dex --output 
C:\Users\Sigmac\AndroidStudioProjects\Voting\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug
\classes-b6f615fe9376219a5b11445078329964f51dafd9.jar C:\Users\Sigmac
\AndroidStudioProjects\Voting\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support
\appcompat-v7\21.0.2\classes.jar

Error Code:
1

Output:
Den angivne sti blev ikke fundet. (The specified path was not found.)

* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option 
to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 30.911 secs

Den angivne sti blev ikke fundet. (The specified path was not found.)
```

I have tested that this eksist:
C:\Users\Sigmac\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat

This folder eksist but is emty
C:\Users\Sigmac\AndroidStudioProjects\Voting\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\

and this eksist
C:\Users\Sigmac\AndroidStudioProjects\Voting\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.2\classes.jar

I have google and search this site but cant finde a solution to this

--stacktrace, --info or --debug don't change the result

I have tryed directly from cmd whit same result
and I have tryed "" the path

Can any point me to a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82099 which should be fixed in the 24.0.1 release of the SDK, which is available now.

The bug is that an internal script that finds the distribution of Java isn't working correctly on 32-bit Windows systems.

Comment: A mix of installing and uninstalling and editing

C:\Users\Annika\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat to

    set java_exe=
    if exist    "%~dp0..\tools\lib\find_java.bat" call        "%~dp0..\tools\lib\find_java.bat"
    if exist "%~dp0..\..\tools\lib\find_java.bat" call "%~dp0..\..\tools\lib\find_java.bat"
    if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
    set java_exe=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe 

got it to work

Comment: I don't know if I did it wrong but it did not solve the issue alone.