# Failed to complete Gradle execution

Tags: android, android-studio

When I tried to run Android application I got error as "Failed to complete Gradle execution . Cause:"

[image]

In Gradle console I got error as:

```
* What went wrong:
The system cannot find the path specified.
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexBetaDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
D:\Android set up\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat --dex --output D:\android-5thDec\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\beta\debug\jackson-databind-2.4.4-47301a2fc4ef9e8c53b857d7529f32f6ef237b60.jar C:\Documents and Settings\ppd\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.4.4\e2ff13c3de2f5a2ab2449a3dace2b0d1c37bd8ee\jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar
Error Code:
1
Output:
The system cannot find the path specified.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug     option to get more log output.
```

After google I got  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748085/android-studio-giving-us-following-error/21752326#21752326) But when I tried to delete key it cant be deleted.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396172/android-studio-1-0-gradle-error-1-the-specified-path-was-not-found/27408734#27408734

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing Android studio v1.0 and changing the directory of sdk manager solved the issue for me.

Download sdk tools from  http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html then extract to your desired location

Click **File - > Project Structure**

In the Android SDK location change it to the path you extracted your sdk folder