# :app:dexDebug Android studio 1.0 Gradle error 1 - The specified path was not found

Tags: android, google-glass, android-gradle-plugin

Error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run
> command:
>
> C:\Users\JosephSlawsky\Android\sdk\android-sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat
> --dex --no-optimize --multi-dex --main-dex-list C:\Users\JosephSlawsky\AndroidStudioProjects\PETS\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\maindexlist.txt
> --output C:\Users\JosephSlawsky\AndroidStudioProjects\PETS\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug
> --input-list=C:\Users\JosephSlawsky\AndroidStudioProjects\PETS\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt

Error Code:

```
1
```

Output:

```
The system cannot find the path specified
```

Running Windows 7 32 bit

I checked, all of the files and directories exist, cannot replicate the command line in a dos window because it is too long to process.

Could the overall problem be related to the fact it is a 440 character command line?

Also made Gradle changes for multidex minify etc.

This is a Google glass application (not very large) that compiles and working well using the last beta of Android Studio.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396172/android-studio-1-0-gradle-error-1-the-specified-path-was-not-found/27408734#27408734

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similiar issue after update. I found the below helpful:

Cause:

In line 27 of tools/lib/find_java.bat has a problem:

```
find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32 || set arch_ext=64
```

You must remove space after "arch_ext=32". Correct code is:

```
find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32|| set arch_ext=64
```

Ref: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82099